# remove ending unbalanced parenthesis

Tags: regex, eclipse, brackets

After a bad global replace in all files on an eclipse PHP project I have to remove all remove ending unbalanced parenthesis that would match the simple regex:

```
^\t*.*\);$
```

The idea would be to remove the ending parenthesis if it is unbalanced in the whole line.

for example:

```
$this->user = JFactory::getUser());
```

becomes

```
$this->user = JFactory::getUser();
```

but

```
    $items = someFunction( $this->get('Data') );
```

remains unchanged whatever the number of balanced brackets it contains.

I precise that my IDE Eclipse "Restore from local history" functionality that would have save me doesn't show any possibility to reverse to previous time version

Any idea appreciated

Comment: Regular expressions are not good for matching balanced or unbalanced brackets.

Comment: Don't you make backups of you data?

Comment: Use 'Replace with > Local History...' in Eclipse to see the history of existing files. 'Restore from local history' is for recovering deleted files.